# Evaluating a Surface Integral of a Sphere with radius t

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, surface-integrals

I had a question about a Surface Integral, I'm not sure if I'm just not understanding the notation, or if I'm right. The Surface Integral is:
$$\iint_{\partial B(0,t)} \psi(\vec x) dS_{\vec x}$$
Where $$\psi(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } |\vec x|\leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Now, is the value equal to $4\pi t^2$, as we are just finding the surface area of the sphere with radius $t$? I'm not sure about the inclusion of $\psi$, but it's just stating that all vectors with magnitude smaller or equal to $1$ will give $1$, which wouldn't affect the outcome of the integral no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to your above integral to be
$$
4\pi t^2
$$
for $t\leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. As you said, 
if $t\leq 1$, you are just evaluating 
$$
\int\int_{\partial B(0,t)}dS_\vec{x}=4\pi t^2
$$
and integrating over $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Isn't $t$ just the size of the sphere we are integrating over? And $\vec x$ is the thing that determines whether or not we integrate over $1$ or $0$?

Comment: yeah $t$ is the size of the sphere you are integrating over, I am not sure what you mean by the second

Comment: I'm confused by why $\psi$ is dependent on $t$, as in your given solution

Comment: when you evaluate a surface integral your domain is the surface of the ball of radius $t$. If $t>1$, then all the $x$ in your domain have norm larger than $1$. In this case $\psi$ vanishes

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!

Comment: @FelicioGrande no problem. Can I ask what book you are using for what I assume is a pde course?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67861/discussion-between-qbert-and-felicio-grande).